# Why is my else statment running the code twice

Tags: php, mysql, database, if-statement, pdo

My code:

```
  <?php
    $name = $_POST["name"];
//establishing connection through PDO
    require("database.php");

    try{
     //querying the firstname data from the people table    
        $sql = $conn->query("SELECT firstname FROM people");

    }catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Data could not be retrieved from the database.";
            exit;
        }

//looping through the array of firstname and echoing it out if it equals to the user input of name. else just echo out sorry no match 
    while($theRow = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    if(strtolower( $name ) == strtolower( $theRow["firstname"] ) && isset($_POST['name']) ){
    echo $theRow['firstname'] . "<br />";
    }else {
        echo 'Sorry no match';
        exit;
    }
    }
    ?>
```

the require database.php is just establishing connection to my database using PDO.

I just have 2 rows in my database with

> > 'firstname' of
>
> - Jack
> - Bob

and if in my input field anyone types one of those 2 names php will echo out that name from the people table in the database. Very simple but the only problem I am having is on my else statement I wanted it to echo out *Sorry no match* if the input field of name is not equal to any name in the database. BUT instead it echo's out Sorry no match once for each name. I understand that I am looping through the array of database name but I only want it to echo *Sorry no match* once if the name input is not equal to a "firstname" in the database.

**EXTRA NOTE:**

I have also tried using a foreach loop instead of the while looping with the fetchAll method instead of just fetch but no luck there. Basically gave me the same results.

**UPDATE ON THE PROBLEM:**

> When I load the page the else statement is already taking effect and
>   echoing out *Sorry no match* even before I set a name in the input.
>   and if I type the wrong name it ill echo out *Sorry no match* twice if
>   I type the correct name it will echo out the name out of the database
>   and *Sorry no match* once.

**FIGURED IT OUT:**

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
require("database.php");

try{
    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT firstname FROM people WHERE firstname = ?");
    $sql->bindParam(1,$name);
    $sql->execute();

}catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Data could not be retrieved from the database.";
        exit;
    }

$theRow = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(strtolower( $name ) == strtolower( $theRow["firstname"] ) ){
echo $theRow['firstname'] . "<br />";
}else{
    echo 'no match'; 
}
?>
```

Turns out I did not even need a loop do to the WHERE claus only getting the firstname that matched $_POST['name'] so it was just a matter of when to out put that data and that was when the if statement came in. But if I had to output more than one single data I would of probably used a foreach loop like so:

```
if(strtolower( $name ) == strtolower( $theRow["firstname"] ) ){
foreach( $theRow as $row ){
    echo $row . "<br />";
    }
    }else{
        echo 'no match'; 
    }
```

If anyone sees any problem with this code or my method please do let me know. Thank you

Comment: Try using break; instead of exit;

Comment: no luck, but I updated my question to give a better understanding on what the problem is exatcly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you seem to answer your own question: Why is the else statement running the code twice? Ans: it's not; it's running it once for each iteration of the loop, because you put it in the loop.

Just change your SQL to:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT firstname FROM people where firstname = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($name));
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

And it'll either return 1 or 0 rows. So your `if` statement will look like this:

```
if($result->num_rows) // True if num_rows > 0; else false
```

And put your `while` loop *inside* your `if` statement. Keep your else statement to just `echo 'Sorry no match';`.

Comment: You should use a prepared statement, you are introducing an sql injection vulnerability where the OP has none.

Comment: you should probably use a prepared statement http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?lq=1

Comment: Fair enough; I was more trying to get at the logic of if/else. I'll update it.

Comment: Never mind about the connection its working again but if I move my while statement in my if statement it gives me a blank page.

Comment: You have a syntax error and unfortunately by default PHP doesn't tell you about them so you can fix them, it just gives you a blank page. Enable error reporting in your PHP app and try again.

Comment: Hey so I figured it out and just updated my code. Please do let me know if you see anything wrong at all with my code. Thanks a ton Robert